# Kafka Streams App fails to scale out due to subscription regex error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am running a kafka streams application, and I started a separate jar file on a separate server with the same consumer group id.

It fails to consume and shuts down citing this error:

```
Assigned partition XXXX-KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000009-repartition-10 for non-subscribed topic regex pattern; subscription pattern is Right-topic|Left-topic|XXXX-KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000003-repartition|XXXX-KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000008-repartition
```

Comment: If you say a "separate jar file" do you mean the "same" jar as in the first machine or a different one? It must be the same one, otherwise you need to use different application IDs.

Comment: yes same jar. Just scp'd onto a separate machine, by separate I mean that I am running it on a separate node

Comment: Hmmm... And both subscribe to the same topics? What version are you using?

Comment: Yes, exact same topics. I am using the kafka streams version 1.0.0 dependency

Comment: Might be a bug. AK 1.0.1 and AK 1.1.0 will be release soon. Maybe it's fixed there. Can you create a JIRA and attach the log files in DEBUG mode. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks